# Turning categories of one column into multiple columns on a dataframe using r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
df1 <- data.frame(familia=c("Gonzales","Perez","Martinez","Gonzales","Perez","Martinez"), 
  anio=c(2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021), 
  numero=c(3,4,2,2,4,1))
```

I would like to rearrange it so that each of the "anio" categories turn into a different column, getting a dataframe like this one:

```
df2 <- data.frame(familia=c("Gonzales","Perez","Martinez"), 
  anio2020=c(3,4,2), 
  anio2021=c(2,4,1)
```

I tried using pivot_wider, but that didn't work. Is there an easy way to achive it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical `pivot_wider`operation

```
library(tidyr)

df1 |> pivot_wider(names_from = anio,
                   values_from = numero,
                   names_glue = "anio{anio}")

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  familia  anio2020 anio2021
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Gonzales        3        2
2 Perez           4        4
3 Martinez        2        1
```